# Proposition 8.3.4 in Donald L. Cohn's Book "Measure Theory" , page 258

Tags: polish-spaces

Proposition: $X,Y$ Polish spaces. $A \subset X$ a Borel subset. Then: 
$f$ is Borel measurable if and only if its graph is a Borel subset of $X \times Y$.

my Question: I can't see where in the proof we need that graph(f) is a Borel subset instead of only beeing an analytic subset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no problem with what you say.

Your statement is "if and only if".  You prove $f$ Borel $\Longrightarrow$ graph is Borel. The converse is true: graph is Borel $\Longrightarrow f$ is Borel.  This much (Prop. 8.3.4) can be proved without the theory of analytic sets.

But you noted that more is true:  graph is anaytic $\Longrightarrow f$ is Borel.  This is also true, but (of course) requires the theory of analytic sets.  If $E$ is Borel, then both $f^{-1}(E)$ and its complement 
$A \setminus f^{-1}(E) = f^{-1}(Y \setminus E)$ are analytic, so $f^{-1}(E)$ is Borel.